# "Shared Folder" disappeared in Excel after an Office 365 update

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

We were pushed a Office update recently and the "Shared Folder" tab that we used for sideloading Office Javascript apps from the network share was completely removed. Does anyone have more information on how to get this folder back or what the work around is for test development?

[Update That was Pushed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqvYT.png)

[Missing Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsTFY.png)

I talked to IT and they think it could be because of something around xll add-ins being disabled in one of the updates? I dont think office javascript creates xll but maybe it has something to do with that change in Excel.

Comment: I have a later build and I still have the "Shared Folders" tab. If you don't get an answer here in the next couple of days, try creating an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Try installing the latest Excel version first. I've got installed 2304 version.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I wish I could. My job controls and decides what updates we all get pushed to our computers. Very strict.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks I have opened an issue there as well since its time sensitive.

Comment: If the issue has been fixed in any later release - what are you going to do then?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I'm hoping its maybe a feature that the Office 365 Admin has accidentally disabled (waiting to hear back from Microsoft). If that isn't the case, i'm hoping that giving the Admin a manifest that points to localhost will allow us to continue local development.

Comment: Don't forget to update the post here so other users may find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't heard any answer back on the office-js repo so for now we discovered that office365 excel workbooks still had the feature to upload a manifest. Keep in mind the payload limits of the web version of excel. We work with large sets of data and needed to write code to handle batching of the data for office online. Weirdly enough the manifests we use to sideload on Excel Desktop did not work when adding them to Office Web so we had to modify them by trial and error. The manifest validator will say the manifest is valid but the upload would still fail. Anyways, this is our work around for now.